# An error with a recursive function in a maze generating algorithm in Java using Eclipse

Tags: java, recursion, console

this is my first try at java, so I decided to write a maze generating algorithm. I already wrote it in C# so I thought it'd be handy to write something I've done before. I use eclipse to write and compile Java.

After I finished writing my program, and it didn't give me any errors or whatsoever, I tried to run it, but it gives a weird output in the console: that says: `at helloWorld.mazeAlgorithm(helloWorld.java:52)` for as much times as the height and width of the maze I'm trying to generate. I've got no clue what to do, and I also couldn't find anything on the internet.

(and I know that my code is probably really bad, but I was kind of in a hurry, and I just wanted to see if I could write something quickly.)
Here it is:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class helloWorld extends Applet
{
    final int horizontalSize = 10;
    final int verticalSize = 10;
    final int LEFT = 1;
    final int UP = 2;
    final int RIGHT = 3;
    final int DOWN = 4;

    ArrayList<cell> visitedCells;
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        initialize(g);
        cell startCell = new cell();
        startCell.x = 0;
        startCell.y = 0;
        mazeAlgorithm(startCell, g);
    }
    public void initialize (Graphics g)
    {

        for (int x = 0; x< horizontalSize*10+1; x=x+10)
        {
            g.drawLine(x, 0, x, verticalSize*10);
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < verticalSize*10+1; y=y+10)
        {
            g.drawLine(0, y, horizontalSize*10, y);
        }

        visitedCells = new ArrayList<cell>();
        cell currentCell = new cell();
        currentCell.x = 0;
        currentCell.y = 0;
        visitedCells.add(currentCell);

    }
    public void mazeAlgorithm(cell currentCell, Graphics g)
    {
        ArrayList<cell> neighbourCells = getUnvisitedNeighbourCells(currentCell);
        while(neighbourCells.size()> 0)
        {
            cell nextCell = neighbourCells.get(randomNumber(neighbourCells.size()-1));
            removeWall(nextCell, g);
            visitedCells.add(nextCell);
            mazeAlgorithm(nextCell, g);
            neighbourCells = getUnvisitedNeighbourCells(currentCell);
        }
        return;
    }

    public ArrayList<cell> getUnvisitedNeighbourCells(cell cellToCheck)
    {
        ArrayList<cell> unvisitedNeighbourCells = new ArrayList<cell>();
        cell tempCell = new cell();

        tempCell.x = cellToCheck.x-1;
        tempCell.y = cellToCheck.y;
        tempCell.direction = LEFT;
        if (cellToCheck.x > 0 && !visitedCells.contains(tempCell))
            unvisitedNeighbourCells.add(tempCell);
        tempCell.x = cellToCheck.x;
        tempCell.y = cellToCheck.y-1;
        tempCell.direction = UP;
        if (cellToCheck.y > 0 && !visitedCells.contains(tempCell))
            unvisitedNeighbourCells.add(tempCell);
        tempCell.x = cellToCheck.x+1;
        tempCell.y = cellToCheck.y;
        tempCell.direction = RIGHT;
        if (cellToCheck.x < horizontalSize-1 && !visitedCells.contains(tempCell))
            unvisitedNeighbourCells.add(tempCell);
        tempCell.x = cellToCheck.x;
        tempCell.y = cellToCheck.y+1;
        tempCell.direction = DOWN;
        if (cellToCheck.y < verticalSize-1 && !visitedCells.contains(tempCell))
            unvisitedNeighbourCells.add(tempCell);
        return unvisitedNeighbourCells;
    }

    public void removeWall(cell Cell, Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        switch(Cell.direction)
        {
        case LEFT:
            g.drawLine(Cell.x*10, Cell.y*10-10, Cell.x*10, Cell.y*10);
            break;
        case UP:
            g.drawLine(Cell.x*10-10, Cell.y*10, Cell.x*10, Cell.y*10);
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            g.drawLine(Cell.x*10-10, Cell.y*10-10, Cell.x*10-10, Cell.y*10);
            break;
        case DOWN:
            g.drawLine(Cell.x*10-10, Cell.y*10-10, Cell.x*10, Cell.y*10-10);
            break;
        }
        return;
    }

    private int randomNumber(int max)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(max);
    }
}

class cell
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int direction;
}
```

A lot of thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you would give more of the stack trace, especially the part just above the "at helloWorld.mazeAlgorithm(helloWorld.java:52)"

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is probably a StackOverflowException and here's why:

getUnvisitedNeighborCells creates a new tempCell and then checks to see if the visited collection contains it.  Because you haven't overridden the equals method on the cell class it will only check the object reference, which will not be the same because you just created a new instance for tempCell, so the `contains` call returns false, so you never really mark a cell as visited.

To fix it, you should override the equals method (and hashCode) for your cell object so that it compares x, y, and direction, then your contains call will return true and you will get out of your infinite traversal.

Comment: Ah I think I understand what you mean. Thanks for investing your time! Let's see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a method problem, more than a coding problem or java problem. Most students begin like this : write all the code that's in your head and run it when it's done.

But that's a way for programming gurus and there are chances you will need years of experience before it works that way.

Programming obeys to the paradigm of "divide & conquer" : when you have a big problem, you break it into pieces and you solve small problems. If there are even too big...you know what to do : you break it again. And so on.

This allows you to solve more specific problems and, more than all, a possibility to check if every small problem is well solved. That's the approach.

No one wants to solve this question as there are too many problems to solve at once.

- Divide them, isolate every method, call it in a small program and find your problems one by one. (Do you know about tests ?)
- Trace your program (put system.out.println) every where you think it is necessary to print out values. Or debug. But you must understand and be able to run all along with your program.

Comment: You are absolutely right, and I usually am a lot more patient, but this time I just kind of rewrote my C# program in Java, (wrongly assuming that it'd work pretty much the same) but I already discovered that it's not entirely the same language.

Comment: Also, I don't know very much about tests. Do you have a link to a site that explains it? (or a short explanation's also welcome:))